# Emacs: add hostname to mode line?

Tags: emacs

I'd like to display the output of (getenv "HOSTNAME") somewhere in my mode line.  My display-time-mode is set to 't', so I'm already displaying time, load level and a mail flag in the mode line.  Is there an easy way to get the hostname in there, too?

I'd like to have this because I'm ssh'd into 3 remote machines, all running emacs from a common set of init files, and I'd like some fast easy unobtrusive way to know which machine I'm working on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried the above answers and was not particularly successful (I'm running emacs 23).  After much investigation, I ended up just putting `system-name` into my `mode-line-format` as follows:

```
;; Set the modeline to tell me the filename, hostname, etc..
(setq-default mode-line-format
  (list " "
        ; */% indicators if the file has been modified
        'mode-line-modified
        "--"
        ; the name of the buffer (i.e. filename)
        ; note this gets automatically highlighted
        'mode-line-buffer-identification
        "--"
        ; major and minor modes in effect
        'mode-line-modes
        ; if which-func-mode is in effect, display which
        ; function we are currently in.
        '(which-func-mode ("" which-func-format "--"))
        ; line, column, file %
        'mode-line-position
        "--"
        ; if vc-mode is in effect, display version control
        ; info here
        `(vc-mode vc-mode)
        "--"
        ; hostname
        'system-name
        ; dashes sufficient to fill rest of modeline.
        "-%-"
        )
)
```

I've detailed this and other things I discovered about the emacs modeline in a [posting on my website](http://www.hollenback.net/index.php/EmacsModeLine).

Answer (score 10):

To build on Sean Bright's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778508/emacs-add-hostname-to-mode-line/778533#778533), specifically you can do this:

```
(let ((pos (memq 'mode-line-modes mode-line-format)))
  (setcdr pos (cons (getenv "HOSTNAME") (cdr pos))))
```

This assumes that `'mode-line-modes` is a part of your `'mode-line-format`, which it is by default.  Because you're modifying the list pointed to by the variable `'mode-line-format`, you don't have to set the default value.  If you were setting the variable itself, you'd have to do something like:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format (build-list-that-contains-(getenv "HOSTNAME")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also append junk to the `global-mode-string` variable:

```
(defvar my-hostname (concat " " (system-name)))
(setq global-mode-string (append global-mode-string '(my-hostname)))
```

Those two lines are probably sufficient for something static like your hostname.

If you have something more dynamic you can set up a timer with `run-at-time` to update the string (`my-hostname` in this example).  Take a look at the definition of `display-time-mode` for a nice little example.